# Text editors with encryption plugins?

Tags: macos, encryption, text-editors, openssl

I am looking for a text editor which supports [openssl encryption](http://osxdaily.com/2007/05/02/quickly-encrypt-a-file-with-openssl/) as a plugin. So, instead of manually:

- decrypt a file in shell
- edit it in the text editor
- encrypt the file in shell

Hopefully, the plugin can take care of the above human steps and only ask for password when opening and closing the file.

Comment: OpenSSL is a network protocol layer... how does this relate to a text editor?

Comment: @Flimzy: The OpenSSL CLI tool can also encrypt and decrypt binary data. See the `enc` predicate.

Comment: [EncryptPad](http://evpo.net/encryptpad) does exactly what you ask but OpenPGP encryption instead of OpenSSL. This text editor does not need a plug-in. Encryption is its main functionality. You don't need to install anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [openssl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2012) plugin for [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) can do this, although I've never used it myself. I do use the [gnupg.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645) plugin however. I'm not sure why you specifically want to use OpenSSL for encryption, but unless you know what you're doing I would suggest GnuPG instead (OpenSSL is a more low level tool and one can still do the wrong thing with ciphers if they aren't used properly). GnuPG can do [symmetric encryption](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r656.html) (i.e. a passphrase) as well as public/private key encryption.

Comment: One reason to choice `openssl`: it's pre-installed on a mac.

Comment: OpenSSL supports a number of different ciphers including 3DES and AES. I think "using OpenSSL encryption" would read better as "using OpenSSL for encryption".

Answer (score 2):

[Textmate](http://macromates.com/) includes the ability to encrypt and decrypt using AES. If you look into the bundle that does this, you can see it is using openssl to do the encryption/decryption. You could easily modify the bundle if needed for different parameters, ciphers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't use OpenSSL, Vim can encrypt a file using Blowfish. See `:h encryption` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime also has an OpenSSL encryption package [OpenSSL](https://github.com/mediaupstream/SublimeText-Crypto).